# How to simplify x && (!y || (y && z))

Tags: c++

Is there a better way to check whether `x && (!y || (y && z))` is true?
I guess I could create a function for that and do something like `x && not_or_and(y, z)` to mitigate some of the pain. But is this really all I can do?

Comment: The rule to simplify this is: `x || (y && z) == (x || y) && (x || z) ` See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Try drawing a truth table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ignoring side effects in the expressions, this is logically equivalent

```
x && (!y || z)
```

The additional check you're doing in for `y` in `(y && z)` is redundant, because if you get to the point where you need to check that part of the expression at all, you've already determined that `!y` is false, which implies that `y` is true.

Comment: Considering side effects, aren't they sort of unpredictable because of possible compiler optimizations? I imagine any good compiler will optimize it to this anyway.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. But what I'm implying (when I say "Ignoring side effects"), is that it's possible that `x`, `y` and `z` are not simple bools. They could, for example, be function calls which return bool. And those functions might have side effects. And, for example, if `x` is true, and `y` is a function call returning `true`, then `y` will be called twice in the OP's code, but only once in mine.

Comment: @Sergey, if token 'y' was a function call that returned a bool, that function could have been called twice in the original expression, vs. never being called twice in the "optimized" version.  And both expression evaluations are predictable as long as there is no operator overloading of && and ||.  Hence, there could be side effects when calling the function in token y twice vs. just once.

Comment: I got an impression at first that a compiler might optimize away that `y` even if it had side effects. But now that I'm thinking about it, it doesn't really make sense: the compiler shouldn't optimize away anything if it may alter behavior of the program, right? So you're right, `y` will be called twice. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: Mostly right. There is one case where the compiler is explicitly allowed to make optimizations that alter the behavior of the program. Look up "Copy Elision". It doesn't apply here though.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yeah I know about copy elision, but it indeed doesn't apply here, so I haven't even thought about it.